Can I run stim on GPU?
I'm trying to run multiple simulations of a stim circuit, in parallel. I am using Cupy to transfer the data to the GPU device but I get errors which because I think I can't run these simulations on the GPU. Is this true and is there a workaround? I'm currently using multiprocessing to run these simulations and it's working good, but I'm curious if it would better on the GPU.

No, you can't run stim on GPU. Stim is a C++ python extension, so CuPy won't work on it.
The arithmetic intensity of simulating stabilizer circuits is low anyways, so it's not really playing to the strengths of the GPU.
